# How to mirror the entire canvas in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

I have a very simple drawing with a single object on the canvas. I have finished working on it and exported the result, and now I need the mirrored counterpart. I could easily mirror the exported PNG except that I generate a couple of them with different resolutions, so it's much more logical to do this in AI.

I have found Object - Transform - Reflect, but here's the problem: the object is offset to the left inside the canvas, and after mirroring it remains offset to the left, but I need it to be offset to the right. In other words: how to mirror objects about the center line of the canvas instead of the center line of the object itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a box the same size as the canvas.
2. If there are objects that fall off of the canvas, then I would create a clipping mask so everything is contained inside the artboard. We want the mirror to happen based on the box we created.
3. Reflect the objects or clipping mask

[image: reflect demo]

Comment: Thank you very much! I would have never figured it out on my own, but now I understand how this works.